# Jade block expansion: How to break out of a block on a single line?

Tags: pug

You can [add nested tags](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#block-expansion) on a single line with `:`; e.g.,

```
ul
  li.first: a(href='#') foo
  li: a(href='#') bar
  li.last: a(href='#') baz
```

But what if I want to add two sibling elements under one parent? e.g.,

```
button.btn.btn-danger
    i.icon-trash.icon-white
    |  Delete
```

gives the desired output:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</button>
```

But is there a way to do it on one line? Some other magical operator to go in place of `???` perhaps? I can't even do it on 2 that I can figure out.

```
button.btn.btn-danger: i.icon-trash.icon-white ??? Delete
```

Comment: Found one way: `button.btn.btn-danger <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete`

Comment: That's cheating Mark...

Comment: @MikeCauser: Uh huh...then post me a real solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid its not possible this way.

Jade 0.13 introduced mixin to help achieve this kind of task with a single line.

Here is how I would define the mixin:

```
  mixin icon-button(type,icon,label)
    button.btn(class=type)
      i(class=icon)
      | #{label}
```

Now you can use a single line to render your button:

```
mixin icon-button('btn-danger','icon-trash icon-white','Delete')
```